# Jquery side menu is severely lagging on some pages

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu

http://neopoints.in/
On the index, the menu on the side is completely normal. It loads fine.

http://neopoints.in/buy/buy-items
On this page, the side menu is expanded and it lags the whole page.

Does anyone know why it's doing this?
I'm also running the site on Wordpress.
Thanks.

Comment: There is an error found in the buy items page. The livequery function is not defined. Maybe you forgot to include the js file?

Comment: Did you get your problem fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery.noConflict() in

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://neopoints.in/index.php?wpsc_user_dynamic_js=true&#038;ver=3.8.6.419073'></script>
```

which is before you are loading the livequery plugin. Thatswhy it does not recognize the livequery as a function. And when javascript fails at some point, JS stops running the rest.

Comment: Thank you for replying! So what would I need to do to fix it?

Comment: @Nadia Well try putting the livequery plugin before that js file.

Comment: :( I don't know where to edit that. It's all in Wordpress stuff, ugh I'm so sorry that I don't understand.